# intellij failed to initialize rendering library

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

i use intellij for android development .
i try to render certain layout in my project and it failed to render it with stackoverflow error. 
the only think special about this layot is that it uses YouTubeFragment (youtube windows i use).

this is the layout file :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.tubefm.activities.VideoPlayerActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="497dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPlayerTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="&lt;Artist> - &lt;Song>"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <fragment
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
        android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewPlayerTitle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/layout_video_player"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/player_footer_bg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@layout/bg_player_footer"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp">

        <!-- Player Buttons -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@layout/rounded_corner"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">

            <!-- Backward Button -->
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnBackward"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_backward"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"/>
            <!-- Play Button -->
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_play"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"/>
            <!-- Forward Button -->
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnForward"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_forward"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"/>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pBarLoadingNewSong"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/youtube_fragment"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

sometimes it throws Java.Lang.StackOverflowError.

do you know what can i do beside uninstall and install it again? :)